# mimic C array of struct processing in JavaScript performancewise

Tags: javascript, arrays, struct

In C it is possible to get a large amount of data records of mixed type processed quite effective. For example, compute a record as function of another like:

```
struct TypeA{
    int i;
    boolean b;
}

struct TypeA{
    long int l;
    float f;
}

struct TypeA as[1000];
struct TypeB bs[1000];

for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    bs[i]=someFunction(as[i]);
```

the `as` will be read lineary and the `bs` written likewise, so it's easy to exploit the CPU's memory or processing bottleneck without much overhead.

In JavaScript, it may be (but is unlikely?) that sequentially created JS objects will produce code that optimized. 
On the other hand, the data could be split to more arrays of the used types, like `Float32Array` and such, and many more then two arrays will have to be read and written by `someFunction`, resulting in some more sequential memory access streams.

Is there another style of doing this efficent?

Comment: Maybe looking at code compiled to asm.js from C or other languages would give more precise clues...

Comment: However, asm.js would allow for true integer types while JS would not, so the results may not apply.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript I wrote this C-code like this :

```
var as =new Array(1000),
    bs =new Array(1000);

/* struct TypeA */
var TypeA = function(x,y) {
    this.i = x;
    this.b = y;
   return this;
}

var TypeB = function(x,y) {
    this.l = x;
    this.f = y;
}

var someFunction = function(a,b) {
   // doing something ....
   b.l = a.i*2;
   b.f = a.b?0.0:100.0;
}

/** init array first**/
for(var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    as[i] = new TypeA(i+1, i & 1);
    bs[i] = new TypeB(0,0.0);
}


for(var i=0; i<1000; i++)
    someFunction(as[i],bs[i]);
```

I think it's the more efficient that I can write.

Comment: That is a very straight forward way, and the JavaScript runtime may optimize it quite well. However I guess it is still quite inefficient in respect to the C equivalent. If I have some spare time, I will try a benchmark of this.